# Catching the value at index.js

Tags: next.js13

In the nextjs app which has 4 routes

1.blog
2.about
3.contact
4.index.js serves as a homepage (/)

is it possible when I click on the link
https://localhost:3000/giftcard/21219
I am able to get `21219` in my index.js

```
You cannot define a route with the same specificity as a optional catch-all route ("/" and "/[[...giftcard]]")
```

Comment: Hey! Please could you provide a reproduction ( code snippet, sandbox .. ) to help you?